# RegEx for a specific word within HTML

Tags: php, regex

I am new to RegEx and haven't been able to figure out what is likely a simple problem.  I need to match a list of specific words within a block of HTML.

For example, I have a list of words:

- ASDF
- ZXCV
- QWER

And the following HTML:

`<p>ASDF jumped over the ZXCV of QWER.</p>`

I am using `preg_replace_callback()` with array of RegEx to match, such as `/\bASDF\b/`, but that will only find `ASDF` surrounded by spaces, and doesn't take into account symbols, such as the beginning/end of tags or punctuation.

I've been staring at RegEx sheets for hours, and am stuck on this one.  Any advice you could give me to get started would be most appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bASDF\b
```

Will match

```
<p>ASDF</p>
<p>foo ASDF bar</p>
<p>&nbsp;ASDF&gt;</p>
<p>foo ASDF.</p>
```

What are you having trouble not matching?

Comment: Aha!  Thank you for your help Seth.  I've been banging my head on this one, and it turns out the problem wasn't the RegEx part at all!  I will close this question, as my real problem was completely unrleated, but thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: planning on it, but SO won't let me unless I wait a few more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take  the HTML tags out of the equation and only work with *text nodes*.

Therefore, strip away the HTML or use something like DOMDocument to parse the elements, and then use the regex on the text nodes.

Also, `\b` should consider `>` a boundary because it is not a word character.

Comment: That isn't appropriate in my case, as I need the result to be back in HTML.  Otherwise I would do exactly as you suggest.  I am dynamically adding links to a handful of specific words.

Comment: @Brad A DOM parser can recreate your HTML fine :)

Comment: While generally I agree with you (and would never actually try to parse HTML with RegEx), I think that is a bit overkill for this application.  But, I will keep that idea in my back pocket.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to match any of those words or all of them? If it's any, you can just do (ASDF|ZXCV|QWER). If it's all those words, what's the criteria for matching all words?

Check out this resource, http://www.regular-expressions.info and I strongly recommend that you pick up a copy of this book, Mastering Regular Expressions, by Jeffrey Friedl, http://regex.info.